# Publish data in Facebook using different user account

Tags: node.js, facebook, oauth

I have created a facebook developer app and trying to run the below service

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=TEST&app_id=<app_id>&access_token=<access_token>
```

I am getting the proper response as mentioned in this link [facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed)
I am generating the access token by logging into my facebook credentials. But for the same app if my friend is trying to login using his facebook credentials, is giving the below error

```
{
error: {
message: "(#200) The target user has not authorized this action"
type: "OAuthException"
code: 200
}-
}
```

Can somebody help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: He have not given the app publish_actions permission then

Answer (score 0):

The `publish_actions` permission needs to get approved by Facebook before you can use it for any user without a role in the App (Developer, Admin, Tester). It´s called **Login Review**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Login Review which you probably haven't pased yet, as @luschn mentioned.

Furthermore, you seem to do a GET call instead of a POST:

```
POST /v2.2/me/feed
```

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#publish